# R: Convert date format horizontally

Tags: r

I have a list of un-continue dates as a data.frame

```
1985-05-02
1985-07-13
1986-05-04
1999-09-05
2001-06-06
```

I need to write it horizontally with a / space to a text file like this:

```
1985-05-02/1985-07-13/1986-05-04/1999-09-05/2001-06-06
```

It is possible to do that by R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `paste` function, calling the `collapse` parameter.

```
df <- read.table(text = "1985-05-02
1985-07-13
1986-05-04
1999-09-05
2001-06-06")
paste(df$V1, collapse = "/")
# [1] "1985-05-02/1985-07-13/1986-05-04/1999-09-05/2001-06-06"
```